# Java How to delete a Field Using ASM?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I need to Delete a field In a Class file Using ASM, But im not able to Find anything that works,

```
for(FieldNode field : classNode.fields) {
    if(field.name.equals("max") && field.value.equals(30)) {
        classNode.fields.remove(field);
        System.out.println("***DELETED " + field.name + " ***");
    }
}
```

Its giving me a Exeption: 
**DELETED max**
`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/223929/5128464)...

Answer (score 1):

Deleting something from a Collection while iterating over it is a bad idea and will **everytime** throw a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

If you operate on Java 8 or newer, please consider using [Collection::removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) and give it a predicate lambda to select the items to remove.

In your case this might work:

```
classNode.fields.removeIf(field -> field.name.equals("max") && field.value.equals(30));
```